# Prove that$\sum_{n: a_n<x} 1 = $#{$n: a_n\le x$}$\sim \frac{x}{(log x)^2}$

Tags: number-theory

Let {$p_n$}n ∈N be the sequence of prime numbers, so that p1 = 2, p2 = 3, and so on. For every n ∈ N, let $$ p_n=m;  a_n := p_m.$$
 Prove that$\sum_{n: a_n<x} 1 = $#{$n: a_n\le x$}$\sim \frac{x}{(log x)^2}$

I'm in trouble with this exercise. I think a good hint can be to use prime number theorem to deduce that $$p_n \sim nlog n $$ so that we can deduce the asymptotic for $a_n$ and then compute.

Comment: Could you clarify what $a_n$ is? Is it just the same as $p_n$?

Comment: @LukeCollins It's $p_{p_n}$.

Comment: So $a_n = p_{p_n} \sim p_n \log p_n\sim (n\log n)\log (n\log n)$. Can you finish from there ?

Comment: I wasn't able to write an in the right way so I had to use m ahahaah. I don't think I can end from there sorry. This was using prime number theorem and was how I think I had to start but I don't really now how to do the second part. Another little hint?

Comment: @reuns can you help me please?

Comment: $a_n\sim  n \log n (\log n + \log \log n) \sim n\log^2 n$. To conclude it suffices to show that with $f(n)= n \log^2 n$ then $f(x/\log^2 x)\sim x$.

Comment: Thank you so much!